# Changing elements of a list to match another list

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a list of list and increase the first element in each sublist until it matches an integer on another list...

```
list1=[[2, 13, 22, 40], [8, 13, 22, 40], [24, 13, 22, 40]]
reference_list = [5, 10, 30]
for i in list1: 
    while (i[0] != i) in reference_list:    
        i[0] = i[0] + 1
print(list1)
```

Right now my output is:

```
[[2, 13, 22, 40], [8, 13, 22, 40], [24, 13, 22, 40]]
```

(Nothing is getting modified)
My desired output is:

```
[[5, 13, 22, 40], [10, 13, 22, 40], [30, 13, 22, 40]]
```

(so that the first integer is increased until it matches an integer on the reference_list)

I have dabbled using the set function but I can't seem to get that to work.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Why not just replace it?

Comment: Maybe change to `while i[0] not in reference_list:`. But what if there is no element bigger than i[0] in reference list?

Answer (score 2):

This should work, you "while" condition was using the same iterator for two different lists

```
list1=[[2,13,22,40],[8,13,22,40],[24,13,22,40]]
reference_list=[5, 10, 30]
for i in list1:
    while i[0] not in reference_list:
        i[0]=i[0]+1
print(list1)
```

But as @GrzegorzBokota said, if the first element of list1 is bigger than all of the elements in the reference list, you will have an infinite loop, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

if you replace the reference `list` by a `numpy.array`, you can directly index the element which is the next bigger one:

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [[2,13,22,40],[8,13,22,40],[24,13,22,40]]
reference_list = np.array([5, 10, 30])
for i in list1:
    i[0] = reference_list[reference_list>=i[0]][0]
print(list1)

# [[5, 13, 22, 40], [10, 13, 22, 40], [30, 13, 22, 40]]
```

*Note that this also does not address the problem which occurs if your reference does not provide the biggest value.*
*But this can be solved by checking if the list of all bigger values is empty:*

```
list1 = [[200,13,22,40],[8,13,22,40],[24,13,22,40]]
reference_list = np.array([5, 10, 30])
for i in list1:
    next_bigger = list(reference_list[reference_list>=i[0]])
    if next_bigger:
        i[0] = next_bigger[0]
print(list1)
# [[200, 13, 22, 40], [10, 13, 22, 40], [30, 13, 22, 40]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quantize the first element of each sublist to one of the entries in the reference_list, you could do it with a list comprehension:

```
list1=[[2,13,22,40],[8,13,22,40],[24,13,22,40]]
reference_list=[5, 10, 30]
list1 = [ [next((r for r in reference_list if r>=v[0]),v[0])]+v[1:] for v in list1 ]
print(list1)
```

Your question and example could also be interpreted to mean that each entry in the reference list corresponds to a list at the same position in the list of lists.  If that is the case, you can use zip to traverse both lists in parallel:

```
list1 = [ [max(r,v[0])]+v[1:] for r,v in zip(reference_list,list1) ]
```